# How to have a service to run eternally on Android?

Tags: android, intentservice

Search engines and Android developer website didn't help and I guess you can help with my problem.

I want to make an app for personal use, which is supposed to run all the time on my old tablet (powered all the time). The app will have several features requiring user interaction but independent of those, it should run a background job to check something continuously (real time!) for instance sound detection. It should also always try to connect another device on the network.
That means that job needs to run almost eternally without being killed. Some comments I have found suggested AlarmManager or BroadcastReceiver. But those are triggered by very defined triggers (either time or broadcast). I don't want that, because it should perform its task continuously all the time. This background job should also be able to communicate with the main Activity of my app to report what it is doing and allow user to interact with it (change settings of the job for instance).

Do you know any way how to accomplish this? Is IntentService correct choice for this (hoping that it won't get killed or maybe I should let the Activity to restart it?)

Thanks!

Comment: What you want to create is called hostile takeover malware. Android's APIs for that sort of thing are reserved for Google use.

Comment: I guess Android is "free" and "open source", do you probably mean Google Services, which is usually preinstalled is doing that? Also what is hostile about my purpose?

Comment: My comment hat quite a lot of ironic subtext - and I was of course talking of the "Google Blobs" that do exactly what the (fine and correct) accepted answer says. Only that the "custom ROM" in this case is, what the vendors worked out together with Google. Don't mix up AOSP (Android Open Source Project) with what you get on actual devices.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Do you know any way how to accomplish this?

Build your own custom ROM, with a modified version of Android that contains your code as a native Linux daemon.

Otherwise, what you want is technically impossible.

You can come fairly close by using a foreground `Service` (not an `IntentService`) and returning `START_STICKY` or `START_REDELIVER_INTENT` from `onStartCommand()`. Android may terminate your process from time to time, but it should restart your service automatically after a short while. That service can use its own background threads to do whatever it is that you are trying to do.

Comment: I was afraid of this answer. Could you please also answer why IntentService is not suitable? What is the caveat?

Comment: @Genom: It is designed for transactional work (disk I/O, database I/O, Web service calls, etc.). It is not designed to be used indefinitely, and it adds no value in that use case. You are better off with a regular `Service`, so you have full control over the threading model.

Comment: Ok I have found out that other developers experienced their services being killed, which seems to be the same thing you are telling. Thanks.